# in repeat.for how to index the first item in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia, repeat

I have a template that i want to load for the length of my array.So when i load the page first i want it to load the first item in the array and then when next is clicked it loads the next item.

this is my html

```
<div repeat.for="item of items">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="center">
                    <div>
                        <md-label > ${item.name}</md-label><br /><br />
                        <md-label> ${user.firstName},</md-label><br />
                         <md-label> ${item.Description}</md-label><br />
                        
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col">

                    <md-radio name="myOption" value="0" checked.bind="choice">Never</md-radio><br />
                
                </div>
                <div><a click.delegate="next()">next</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>

async onLoad() {
        this.items= await this.query<ItemQuery, ItemModel>(new ItemQuery({ id: this.id }));
        this.user= await this.query<fetchUser, UserModel>(new fetchUser(this.UserId));
        
        
    }
async next(){}
```

currently its repeating every item in my items array on load.

an example of my array is

```
this.items=[{name:"Test1",description:"this is test 1"}]
[{name:"Test2",description:"this is test 2"}]
[{name:"Test3",description:"this is test 3"}]
```

im not sure how to load on first instance only the values for Test1 and then when next is clicked fetch Test2 details using the above html?

Comment: When the second item is loaded, should the first item still be there? Or should the second item replace the first one?

Comment: it should replace the first one till it reaches the end and stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only one item is being displayed here, you can index into the items array, and increment the index when `next` is clicked.

```js
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="center">
            <div>

                <md-label> ${items[index].name}</md-label><br /><br />
                <md-label> ${user.firstName},</md-label><br />
                <md-label> ${items[index].Description}</md-label><br />

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col">

            <md-radio name="myOption" value="0" checked.bind="choice">Never</md-radio><br />

        </div>
        <div><a click.delegate="next()">next</a></div>
    </div>
</div>

async onLoad() {
    this.index = 0;
    this.items = await this.query < ItemQuery, ItemModel > (new ItemQuery({ id: this.id }));
    this.user = await this.query < fetchUser, UserModel > (new fetchUser(this.UserId));
}

async next(){
    this.index = (this.index + 1) % this.items.length;
}
```

Comment: and if i want to click on a back button do i just minus the index?

Comment: @deanpillow yes